# Phar:// stream wrapper with space in the filename

Tags: php, zip, archive, phar, scandir

so I have a zip file in directory

/pathdodir/the zip file.zip

so I do this:

```
$dir = 'phar:///pathdodir/the zip file.zip';
$file = scandir($dir);
print_r($file);
```

but then this ends up complaining about

> "failed to open dir: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar"

if I rename the zip file such that it has without spaces though ie to thezipfile.zip and then change $dir to thezipfile.zip as well, phar would work and it would print_r the files inside that zip accordingly...

how do I make it so that phar would also work even if there are spaces in the filename?

Comment: %20 instead of the space or use urlencode on the $dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name you use - `phar:///pathdodir/the zip file.zip` - is an URL; it has a schema (`phar://`).

You have to url-encode special characters in URLs, and the space is encoded as `%20`.